# Django with HAPROXY -Session cookie setup - set_cookie('haproxy_cookie_name, 'new_value') doesn't set the new value

Tags: django, session-cookies, haproxy

I have a Django app with a HAPROXY load-balancer.
I am using the Session cookie setup by the Load-Balancer to make the user go always for the same server  to provide persistence as shown in this link:

[https://www.haproxy.com/blog/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/#session-cookie-setup-by-the-load-balancer][1]

for some reason I am wanting to be able to set the cookie So I can choose which server to access each time but reaponse.set.cookie('haproxy_cookie_name, 'new_value') doesn't set the new value
I have also checked the reaponse.set.cookie works on other cookie and it works fine.

Do anyone have any idea why this doesn't work?
Is there other option to set the cookie value (from the server)